# Unable to set value of object before sending it to server

Tags: angularjs

I am calling following code on update button click

```
  $scope.update = function (p) {
                console.log(p);
                console.log(p.id);
                console.log(p.unitPrice);
                alert("ok");
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'update-product',
                    params: {product: p},
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.st === 1) {
                        window.location = "show-product";
                    } else {
                        $scope.msg = data.msg;
                    }
                })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            alert("Opps unable to connect to server");
                        });
            }
```

but this is not sending data in server product object.

On click on update() it is getting following data 
as shown in console at call of log().

`Object {id: 1051, mainProduct: Object, sellingPrice: 234, unitPrice: 234, $$hashKey: "object:3"}`

1051
234

from server it is showing `"Invalid field value for field "product"."`

At server side

```
public String ProductAction extends ActionSupport{
private Product product;
//Product contains id name ...
//getter and setter
public String update(){
System.out.println(getProduct().getId());
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what the server side looks like for this piece of code?

Comment: At the server side i am printing the object `System.out.println(getProduct().getId());`

Comment: Is above code is correct

Comment: What does the server side accept? At the moment you're sending your product as a query param in a POST call, but I believe your server side code expects request content.

Comment: Updated my server code

Answer (score 0):

it should be `data` to post data to server.

```
 $http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'update-product',
     data: {product: p},     <---------  mention here
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
 })
```